# Grouping back-end APIs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

While using AngularJS's $http service I've found hard to manage all urls to backend - they're spread around controller's code. Sometimes they're even duplicated. Mostly all of them are in form of `$http.get('/api/something').then(...)`.

To put all of them into different services sounds quite unreasonable: it is just one line of code with may be just small modifications (like adding header etc).

Other solution could be putting them into constants, but in this case I would still use `$http.get(APIURLs.SomeURL)` that looks like little bit verbose...

So the question is: what is the best way to manage URLs to back-end?

Answer (score 2):

Currently I came up with idea of grouping them into servicies and expose them as calls to $http. Here is my solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/VjqXHBV54bmjKCuGJ4qX?p=preview

Service:

```
.factory('AdminAPI', function($http) {
   var apiMap = {
     'DeleteAuth': {url:'/api/oauth/delete',method:'PUT'},
     'GetInvalidUser': {url:'/api/users/invalid',method:'GET'},
     'CreateItem': {url:'/api/items/create',method:'POST'}     
   };
   var api = {};  
   var prepareCall = function(config) {
     return function(params) {  
       var requestConfig = angular.copy(config);
       if (config.method=='GET')
          requestConfig.params = params;
       else 
          requestConfig.data = params;       
       return $http(requestConfig);
     };
   };
   for(var name in apiMap) 
     api[name] = prepareCall(apiMap[name]);   
   return api;
});
```

And in controllers I do something like:

```
AdminAPI.DeleteAuth({data:123}).then(function(result) {
  //
});
```

In this case I have some abstraction (do not have to inject `$http` into controller), so unit-tests become little bit easier (I do not have to use $httpBackend service, just mock my service calls).

Answer (score 0):

Make use of angular [Module.constant](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module):

- Move reusable settings to single object;
- Define angular module wrapping this object:

  ```
  angular.module('myApp.constants', []).constant('config', {
      ROUTES: {
         home: '/home.html',
         about: '/about.html'
      }
  });
  ```
- load `myApp.constants` module into application with all the others:

  ```
  angular.module('myApp', [
      'myApp.constants',
      'myApp.services',
      'myApp.controllers',
      'myApp.filters',
      'myApp.directives'
  ]);
  ```

After that you can inject `config` dependency and access defined hash.

Comment: Is that what I've meant by "Other solution could be putting them into constants,"? So to use that, you'll need to inject both `config` and `$http`... and also if you have to add some common options to different requests (like headers, cache, timeout etc), you still need to copy-paste...

Answer (score 0):

Good question. My suggested approach is to put the constants in a `constant`declaration like this:

```
angular.module('fooApp').constant('config', {
                                      api: {
                                        baseUrl: 'http://api.example.com/api',
                                        key: 'SECRET_API_KEY',
                                      }
});
```

And you could implement a `httpResourceFactory` that is responsible for creating $http or $resource references that points to different endpoints using the constants defined in config.
This could be implemented in a service.

Then all API endpoint definitions can be put into a single service.

```
angular.module('fooApp').factory('dataService', ['httpResourceFactory',  function(httpResourceFactory) {

    var PUBLIC_API = {};

    PUBLIC_API.Orders = httpResourceFactory('/orders/:id');
    PUBLIC_API.Users = httpResourceFactory('/some-url/users/:id');


    return PUBLIC_API;

  }]);
```

Then in your controller you may inject `dataService` and do stuff like this:

```
$scope.users = dataService.Users.query();
```

Hope this clarified it. I'm in a hurry, so ask more concrete and I will provide more examples later on.

Comment: Nice solution, looks similar to mine. Only one note - `config` dependency is not needed to `dataService`, I assume you need it at `httpResourceFactory`, isn't it?

Comment: Correct! Sloppy example writing.